# Jnlp-файл скачивается вместо запуска

Tags: javaws, java

У меня есть Java web start приложение. И когда я кликаю на кнопку запуска Jnlp-файлов (javaDeploy.createWebStartLaunchButton) открывается окно загрузок браузера и предлагается скачать jnlp-файл, после загрузки можно кликнуть на него - всё нормально запустится. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы Java web start приложение сразу запускалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это потому, что сервер не возвращает правильный MIME-тип и браузер не ассоциирует javaws с файлом, а потом когда он уже скачан, то запуск происходит через виндовые средства, которые ищут по расширению.

JNLP файлам соответствует тип application/x-java-jnlp-file

Например, для апача в файле mime.types

```
application/x-java-jnlp-file JNLP
```

Comment: Понятно.